# how to make blinking text in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

i have done a program in python using pygame...

```
#some code before this...

    def screen4(cS,cC):
    screen.blit(background, backgroundRect)
    drawText1('Oops....!',font4,screen,250,120)
    drawText1(cC,font1,screen,250,210)
    drawText2('i s   t h e   c a p i t a l    o f        ',font1,screen,5,275)
    drawText1(cS,font1,screen,425,275)
    drawText2('F  i  n  a  l     S  c  o  r  e  :    '+str(point),font4,screen,55,375)
    drawText1('P  r  e  s  s     a  n  y      k  e  y     t  o    Q  u  i  t  .  .  .',font2,screen,120,535)
    pygame.display.flip()
    waitForPlayerToPressKey()
```

and it goes on..
i want to display the final score like the text blinking or with any other effects.. is that possible with the code i have done??? pls help me...

Answer (score 0):

I assume `waitForPlayerToPressKey()` does not return until the player presses some key.
If so, without changing much of your code, it is not possible.

If you want to have control over what happens on the screen while waiting for a press, you could have your `waitForPlayerToPressKey()` return true when a button has been pressed.
You could then do something like:

```
while(True):
    drawText()
    flip()
    if(waitForPlayerToPressKey()): 
        return
```

You could then set a [timer](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) - and change some show blit flag every second.

Comment: The timer could decrease text's `set_alpha()` based on time.